# update multiple records in one form using checkboxes / wrong number of arguments rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, updatemodel

I've been bumbling my way through tutorials/forums in an attempt to figure out how update multiple methods using checkboxes.

I need to be able to list my "events" and check or uncheck them if the date is available. I'd like to do this on one form. I know this is possible, but I'm finally coming here after failing to get it working.

With the code I've posted I'm getting "Wrong Number of Arguments, 2 for 1" error.

I've tried these info sources:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes
http://discuss.codeschool.io/t/surviving-apis-with-rails-posting-multiple-records/4776/4
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised

Here's where I'm at

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    put  :verified
    post :make_events
  end
end
```

events_controller.rb

```
def verified
  if Event.update_all(["available", true], :id => params[:event_ids])
    redirect_to step2_path(:pid => @project.id,  :u => current_user.id)
  else
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag verified_events_path(:pid =>  @project.id ), method: :put  do  %>
  <table class="table-event-dates">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><% @these_events.each do |event| %>

        <td><%= check_box_tag "event_id[]", event.id, :value => event.available  %></td>
        <td><label> <%= event.date.strftime("%A, %b. %d %G") %></label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      <% end %>
      </table>

  </div><br><!-- panel-body -->
  <div class="panel-footer2">
    <div class="row">
      <%= submit_tag 'Verify Dates',  :class => 'btn btn-green btn-lg btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In what line do you have this error? Also you have incorrect markup: `<% end %>` should be before `</tr>`

Comment: I have it in the controller:  " if Event.update_all(["available", true], :id => params[:event_ids])"  & thanks for the markup fix.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should work in old-fashioned style:

```
Event.update_all("available = 1", ["id in (?)", params[:event_ids]])
```

perhaps `available = true` or `'true'`, i'm not sure. Or:

```
Event.update_all(["available", true], ["id in (?)", params[:event_ids]])
```

However, maybe you should clear params. Check that they are in correct form (`1, 2, 4`..).

Also you could try this:

```
Event.where(id: params[:event_ids]).update_all(available: true)
```

Comment: I have tried all of those before.  I tried them again just to make sure, and, though the last one gets rid of the error....it makes no changes to the database.  That's my problem with this...either I get the "arguments" error or the form fails to touch the database. The if/else is redirecting as if the method was successful, but it's not. I am so stuck.  Thank you though.

Comment: I should note, that your answer did fix the error I had requested and so I'll mark it helpful...but for others, reading, there is still some other error in my code that is preventing the records from submitting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been stale for a while but for what it's worth, the other error in the code provided that NothingToSeeHere mentions in the comment is:

In the view you have singular event_id

```
<%= check_box_tag "event_id[]", event.id, :value => event.available  %>
```

In the controller you have plural event_ids

```
Event.update_all(["available", true], :id => params[:event_ids])
```

Both the params need to match and be plural. Zishe's last example for how to handle the update on the controller side is the convention for Rails 4.

```
<%= check_box_tag "event_ids[]", event.id, :value => event.available  %>
Event.where( :id => params[:event_ids] ).update_all( :available => true )
```