# Can't get Update_all in a form full of check_box_tag fields to work at all in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I've been having a serious issue with updating a list of records using a simple boolean checkbox.

I need to be able to list my "events" and check or uncheck them if the date is available. I'd like to do this on one form. I know this is possible, but I'm finally coming here after failing to get it working.

When I submit the form, it follows the correct if: redirect path as if the update had succeeded...but the the records remain unchanged and the updated_at also remains unchained.

I've tried these info sources:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes
http://discuss.codeschool.io/t/surviving-apis-with-rails-posting-multiple-records/4776/4
http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple-revised

Here's where I'm at

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    put  :verified
    post :make_events
  end
end
```

events_controller.rb

```
def verified
  if Event.where(id: params[:event_ids]).update_all(available: true)
    redirect_to step2_path(:pid => @project.id,  :u => current_user.id)
  else
    redirect_to show_events_path(:pid => @project.id,  :u => current_user.id)
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag verified_events_path(:pid =>  @project.id ), method: :put  do  %>
  <table class="table-event-dates">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><% @these_events.each do |event| %>

        <td><%= check_box_tag "event_id[]", event.id, :value => event.available  %></td>
        <td><label> <%= event.date.strftime("%A, %b. %d %G") %></label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      <% end %>
      </table>

  </div><br><!-- panel-body -->
  <div class="panel-footer2">
    <div class="row">
      <%= submit_tag 'Verify Dates',  :class => 'btn btn-green btn-lg btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

I've been stuck on this for a while.

There was a similar question that I posted, but the fix was not related to and did not address the error...it did, however, address a different error.  I am sorry to post twice, but it seems like a different problem within my same project.

[update multiple records in one form using checkboxes / wrong number of aruguments rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309225/update-multiple-records-in-one-form-using-checkboxes-wrong-number-of-arugument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the key to my problem turned out to be a mix of not listing the boolean variable and that I had to specify a value for my unchecked checkbox.

This saved me:

controller:

```
def verfied

Event.where(id: params[:event_ids]).update_all({:available => true})
Event.where.not(id: params[:event_ids]).update_all({:available => false})
return redirect_to step2_path(:pid => @project.id, :id => @project.id, :u => current_user.id, :t => @project.template_id)

else 
      redirect_to event_edit_path(:pid => project_id, :u => current_user.id)


end
```

Here's my final code from for the form:

```
 <div class="form-wrap">
          <%= form_tag verified_events_path(:pid =>  @project.id ), method: :put  do  %> 


           <table class="table-event-dates">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th> </th>
              <th> </th>  
            </tr>
          </thead>
           <tbody> 
            <tr><% @these_events.each do |event| %>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "event_ids[]", event.id, event.available  %><%= hidden_field_tag :updated_at,  Time.now %></td>
              <td><label> <%= event.date.strftime("%A, %b. %d %G") %></label></td>

                             </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                          <% end %>
            </table>

          </div><br><!-- panel-body -->
          <div class="panel-footer2">
            <div class="row">

                <%= submit_tag 'Verify Dates',  :class => 'btn btn-green btn-lg btn-block' %>  

            </div>   
          </div>

      </div><!-- panel -->


    </div><!-- col-md-6 --><!-- col-md-6 -->

                  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `params[:event_ids]` to `params[:event_id]`:

```
Event.where(id: params[:event_id]).update_all(available: true)
```

This works for me.

Also use logger to watch params: `logger.debug { "params: #{params[:event_id]}" }`. Most of the problems are in them.

Comment: That doesn't do anything.  Maybe it's a problem with mu form? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: I [created a project](https://bitbucket.org/zishe/test_event) with your code, with fixed code and markup. It works correctly.

Comment: Yes, markup is really horrible:) `div`s should be closed and event iteration should be in one block, as i mentioned before `<% end %>` should be before `</tr>`.

Comment: Oof.  I did try moving the <% end %> like you said, but moved it back because everything got wonky. If there are unclosed divs, that makes sense.  I  don't have time to take your code for a spin right now, but thank you in advance for all your time.

Comment: Unfortunately your code seems to be just what I was finding on the tutorials and didn't solve my problem.  I posted my solution below.  Thank you for your help.